# Why does Capybara think I have an invalid URI scheme format? Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError: Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

When I try to run this one specific test, it gives this error. When I try to run all tests, it fails for another reason. How can I run this one test without this error? It's clearly a valid URL.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>rspec ./spec/features/ctdbase_purchase_spec.rb:28
http://ctdbase.org/  # output of puts
  1) CTD Purchase Unregistered user visits the CTD product page directly and makes purchase
     Failure/Error: visit url

     Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError:
       Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1
     # ./spec/support/ctdbase_support.rb:8:in `visit_ctd'
     # ./spec/features/ctdbase_purchase_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Here is the code

`ctdbase_support.rb`

```
  def visit_ctd(path)
    url = "#{CTD_URL}#{path.starts_with?('/') ? '' : '/'}#{path}"
    puts url
    visit url # line 8
  end
```

`ctdbase_purchase_spec.rb`

```
  before do
    delete_downloads
    visit_ctd '/' # line 11
```

Here is the full backtrace:

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace\catalyst_research>rspec -b ./spec/features/ctdbase_purchase_spec.rb:28
...
  1) CTD Purchase Unregistered user visits the CTD product page directly and makes purchase
     Failure/Error: visit "#{CTD_URL}#{path.starts_with?('/') ? '' : '/'}#{path}"

     Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError:
       Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:874:in `scheme='
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:799:in `block in initialize'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:2355:in `defer_validation'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:796:in `initialize'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:136:in `new'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/uri.rb:136:in `parse'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/addressable-2.5.2/lib/addressable/template.rb:413:in `match'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:151:in `block in matches?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:151:in `any?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:151:in `matches?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/request_pattern.rb:33:in `matches?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:58:in `block in request_stub_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:57:in `each'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:57:in `detect'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:57:in `request_stub_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/stub_registry.rb:50:in `response_for_request'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:79:in `request'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:1165:in `get'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `block in responsive?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:123:in `start_without_connect'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/webmock-3.0.1/lib/webmock/http_lib_adapters/net_http.rb:150:in `start'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/2.4.0/net/http.rb:608:in `start'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:82:in `responsive?'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/server.rb:98:in `boot'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:88:in `initialize'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `new'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara.rb:304:in `current_session'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:45:in `page'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/capybara-2.16.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:50:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.7.2/lib/rspec/rails/example/feature_example_group.rb:29:in `visit'
     # ./spec/support/ctdbase_support.rb:6:in `visit_ctd'
     # ./spec/features/ctdbase_purchase_spec.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:350:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:509:in `block in run_owned_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:508:in `each'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:508:in `run_owned_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:595:in `block in run_example_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:594:in `reverse_each'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:594:in `run_example_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:464:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:494:in `run_before_example'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:253:in `block in run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `block in with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `block in with_around_example_hooks'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `block in run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:606:in `block in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-rails-3.7.2/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:127:in `block (2 levels) in <module:MinitestLifecycleAdapter>'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:447:in `instance_exec'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:375:in `execute_with'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:608:in `block (2 levels) in run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:342:in `call'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:609:in `run_around_example_hooks_for'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:466:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:457:in `with_around_example_hooks'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:500:in `with_around_and_singleton_context_hooks'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example.rb:251:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:628:in `block in run_examples'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `map'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:624:in `run_examples'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:590:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (3 levels) in run_specs'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `map'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:118:in `block (2 levels) in run_specs'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1896:in `with_suite_hooks'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:113:in `block in run_specs'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:79:in `report'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:112:in `run_specs'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:87:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
     # C:/ruby24/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
     # C:/ruby24/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
     # C:/ruby24/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Seems this project is using WebMock. This is the `webmock.rb` file

`spec/config/webmock.rb`

```
require 'webmock/rspec'
WebMock.allow_net_connect!

GOOGLE_STUB_WITHOUT_IP = {
  "city" => "Mountain View",
  "region" => "California",
  "region_code" => "CA",
  "country" => "US",
  "country_name" => "United States",
  "continent_code" => "NA",
  "postal" => "94035",
  "latitude" => 37.386,
  "longitude" => -122.0838,
  "timezone" => "America/Los_Angeles",
  "utc_offset" => "-0700",
  "country_calling_code" => "+1",
  "currency" => "USD",
  "languages" => "en-US,es-US,haw,fr",
  "asn" => "AS15169",
  "org" => "Google LLC"
}

uri_template =
  Addressable::Template.new "https://ipapi.co/{ip_address}/json/"

WebMock.stub_request(:get, uri_template).to_return { |request|
  {
    # FIXME: This should dynamically return the ip address
    # body: GOOGLE_STUB_WITHOUT_IP.merge('ip' => request.ip_address)
    body: GOOGLE_STUB_WITHOUT_IP.merge('ip' => '8.8.8.8').to_json,
    headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you weren't filtering your gems from your backtrace (so we can see exactly what line in Capybara the error is coming from) but as a guess I would say you have probably incorrectly defined `Capybara.app_host` (or possibly `Capybara.server_host`)

Comment: I would use the URI module here instead: `url = URI(CTD_URL); url.path += path;` it will raise an error straight away in your spec if the url is invalid. It will also add the correct protocol (HTTP by default) which is why your spec is failing.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is not a URL. Its an IP address. `http://127.0.0.1` is an url.

Comment: @max Yes I know max, but the URL is printed in the output and it is a valid URL.

Comment: @ThomasWalpole I added the full backtrace and `webmock.rb`. There is no reference to `app_host` nor `server_host` anywhere in the app.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a bug in the combination of WebMock and Addressable - https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/489 and https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/pull/739. The problem is that WebMock ends up creating variations of URLs to compare to templates, and ends up doing something like `127.0.0.1:<some_port>/__identify` when Capybara starts the app. The proper solution is for WebMock to fix the URLs it's sending to Addressable, but you may be able to workaround it temporarily by setting `Capybara.server_host='localhost'` which will cause the URL variation to end up as `localhost:<some_port>/__identify` and Addressable will see `localhost` as a possible scheme (which could be valid).  It's a hack, but it may hold you over until WebMock gets fixed.  Another option would be to stop using URL templates with WebMock and use regex instead.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. It got through the first visit, but failed on another line with `Failure/Error: raise InvalidURIError, "Invalid scheme format: #{new_scheme}"

     Addressable::URI::InvalidURIError:
       Invalid scheme format: 127.0.0.1`

Comment: @Chloe You tried what ? If you mean setting `Capybara.server='localhost'` created an error elsewhere,  then swap from using   `Addressable::Template` and use a regex instead or apply the monkeypatch shown in the webmock issue I linked to.

Comment: The monkey patch did not work either. https://github.com/bblimke/webmock/issues/489#issuecomment-378826298. I ultimately commented `WebMock.stub_request(:get, uri_template).to_return { |request| ...` and the test worked.